# how to rotate image in kinectjs keeping image aligned to top left

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am trying to rotate an image inside a canvas but keeping the image to the top left each rotation is 1/4 reveolution.

My code is :-

```
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function(){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: imageObj.width,
    height: imageObj.height
  });

  var img = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: padding,
      y: padding,
      image: imageObj,
      width: imageObj.width,
      height: imageObj.height,
    });

  layer.add(img);
    stage.add(layer);
   layer.draw();

   });

   $('#rotate-right').on('click', function(){
   img.rotate(90);
   layer.draw();
   });

   });
   imageObj.src = 'img/flippimage3.jpg';
```

The image rotates but off canvas, I have tried to play with offsets but can't seem to figure out exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image rotate around its own centerpoint by setting its offsets to 1/2 its size:

```
var img = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: padding,
    y: padding,
    image: imageObj,
    width: imageObj.width,
    height: imageObj.height,
    offset:{x:imageObj.width/2,y:imageObj.height/2}
});
```

Comment: already tried that, it needs to rotate so that it's positioned top left after rotation

Comment: To clarify then: you want the image flush with the top-left after each quarter rotation?